# Log each statement of SqlDataAdapter C#

Tags: c#, mysql, command, sqldataadapter

Is it possible to log exactly each individual statement which SqlDataAdapter executes on mysql Database, while using .Update() Method in C#?

*(Without having to use SQLProfiler or any other third party programm, but pure C# code)*

Comment: _"log exactly each individual statement"_ what kind of statements?

Comment: @Tim Schmelter The INSERT, DELETE and UPDATE statements with all parameters

Comment: Where do you want to log to? File system? Audit table in the DB? If the latter you could always add a trigger to your table.

Comment: @BDH I want to log it to the file system, e.g. a .txt file.

Comment: I don't think this is just a simple "write a few lines of code and be done with it solution.". Things you would need to consider are performance implications when the text file starts getting bigger, whether to write the log asynchronously. How to deal with errors writing to the file. My advice would be to create a persistence class which accepts calls and logs as required. I would use nLog to do this as it supports file archiving.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the way I solved my problem, thought I'd share it for anyone looking for an idea.

```
    #region generate SQL Update Script
    static void da_RowUpdating(object sender, SqlRowUpdatingEventArgs e)
    {
        string sqlCommand = e.Command.CommandText;

        for (int i = 0; i < sqlCommand.Length; i++)
        {
            string substring = "";
            string paramvalue = "";

            int check = 0;
            int index = 0;

            substring = sqlCommand.Substring(i, 1);
            if (substring == "@")
            {
                if (Int32.TryParse(sqlCommand.Substring(i + 3, 1), out check))
                {
                    index = Convert.ToInt32(sqlCommand.Substring(i + 2, 2));
                    paramvalue = e.Command.Parameters[Convert.ToInt32(sqlCommand.Substring(i + 2, 2)) - 1].Value.ToString();
                    sqlCommand = sqlCommand.Remove(i, 4);
                }
                else
                {
                    index = Convert.ToInt32(sqlCommand.Substring(i + 2, 1));
                    paramvalue = e.Command.Parameters[index - 1].Value.ToString();
                    sqlCommand = sqlCommand.Remove(i, 3);
                }
                sqlCommand = sqlCommand.Insert(i, paramvalue);
            }
        }
        sw.WriteLine(sqlCommand);
        sw.Flush();
    }
    #endregion generate SQL Update Script
```

Answer (score 2):

You could [handle the `DataAdapter` events](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6d1wk41s%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) like `RowUpdating` or `RowUpdated`.

So for your `MySql` database:

```
void OnRowUpdated(object sender, MySqlRowUpdatedEventArgs args)
{
    string sql = args.Command.CommandText;
    bool isStoredProcedure = args.Command.CommandType == CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    foreach (MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlParameter p in args.Command.Parameters)
    {
        string paramName = p.ParameterName;
        DbType dbType = p.DbType;
        MySqlDbType dbType2 = p.MySqlDbType;
        object value = p.Value;
    }
}
```

These events are triggered for every row that gets inserted, updated or deleted.